# Vuex getter for array of objects is not updating properly in module

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuex

I thought I was updating the state incorrectly in a Vuex module, because the component data was **not** updating.

I was working in a store module.

The data was an array of objects and I was updating values in an object, which in some circumstances can be problematic in Vue. But, in my case I was doing it properly. They "should" have been observed changes... But the component was not updating with the change.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was doing everything right and it SHOULD work.

What was actually going wrong was that with the **file name** of the **module**.

The file name of the module /module/user.js which was the same as a piece of state in my main store called 'user'

Even though I didn't use the same state object names, somehow the filename caused an issue... Anyway, I changed the name of the module to /module/userStore.js and that fixed it...

Hope that helps someone...